# Convert multiple strings into an array

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have multiple strings printing from one variable 'words' in a for loop from a json file, then i get these names.

```
with open('list.json', 'r') as i:
    names = json.load(i)

for a in names:
  words = (a['id']['name'])
  print words

'Vincent'
'Jackson'
'Marie'
'Mold'
'Gary'
'Sameul'
```

I want to put all of these names into an array, and keep it inside the variable 'words'.

```
words = ['Vincent','Jackson','Marie','Mold','Gary','Sameul']
```

Comment: Initialize a empty `list` and append `a['id']['name']` in each iteration.

Comment: wow that was fast, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python `lists` are very flexible and can hold completely heterogeneous, arbitrary data, and they can be appended to very efficiently, in amortized constant time. If you need to shrink and grow your list time-efficiently and without hassle, they are the way to go.

You can store them into a [list](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists).

```
words = []
for a in names:
  words.append(a['id']['name'])
```

Or

You can use [list comprehensions](https://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php). This will replace your `for` loop entirely:

```
words = [a['id']['name'] for a in names]
```

> I want to put all of these names into an array, and keep it inside the variable 'words'.

I am assuming you are flexible to use any data structure in Python and by array, you just mean a sequence data type. However, I am adding some information on array for the sake of completeness.

An array is a data structure that stores values of same data type. In Python, this is the main difference between arrays and lists. While python lists can contain values corresponding to different data types, arrays in python can only contain values corresponding to same data type.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('list.json', 'r') as i:
    names = json.load(i)

for a in names:
  words = (a['id']['name'])

wordList = []
for word in words:
    wordList.append(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to python, there's a `List` data structure you might wanna check out. This `List` can hold arbitrary data and you can `append` element in this list.

For your problem, before iterating the `names` you read from the `json` file, initialize a list.

```
list_that_holds_names = []
```

And then, during each iteration, append the element from the `names`

```
for a in names:
  words = (a['id']['name'])
  list_that_holds_names.append(words)
```

Now this `list_that_holds_names` list contains all the names. If you print the list, it will geberate the expected output.

But please, do **Google** stuff or try learning first from **Google** before posting here.

Comment: yeah, sorry, i did try to google but i did not get many results so i came here, i did not know what to google for, thanks tho~!